# Wordpress Media frame pre load images from ids

Tags: uploads, javascript, media-library

Im using custom metabox button to create `wp media frame` with this code,

```
var
    frame,
    selection,
    idsField = $('#_fills_ids');

frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion',
        state:      'gallery-edit',
        editing:    true,
        multiple:   true,
        frame:      'post',
        selection:  selection,
        button: {
          text: 'Use this media'
        }
      });


selection = function() {
    var shortcode = new wp.shortcode({
            tag:      'gallery',
            attrs:    { ids: idsField.val() },
            type:     'single'
        }),
        defaultPostId = wp.media.gallery.defaults.id,
        attachments, selection;
    attachments = wp.media.gallery.attachments( shortcode );

    console.log("s");
    // Bail if we didn't match the shortcode or all of the content.
    if ( ! shortcode )
        return;

    // Ignore the rest of the match object.
    ///shortcode = shortcode.shortcode;

    if ( _.isUndefined( shortcode.get('id') ) && ! _.isUndefined( defaultPostId ) )
        shortcode.set( 'id', defaultPostId );

    attachments = wp.media.gallery.attachments( shortcode );
    selection = new wp.media.model.Selection( attachments.models, {
        props:    attachments.props.toJSON(),
        multiple: true
    });

    selection.gallery = attachments.gallery;

    // Fetch the query's attachments, and then break ties from the
    // query to allow for sorting.
    selection.more().done( function() {
        // Break ties with the query.
        selection.props.set({ query: false });
        selection.unmirror();
        selection.props.unset('orderby');
    });

    return selection;
  };
```

I have 3 attachment ids comma separated string '111, 125, 335', 
But its not populating any thumbnails on gallery edit frame.
[image]

Comment: What is `idsField`?

Comment: it's a hidden input field jQuery object that containing image ids as comma separated string.

Comment: Are you sure `attrs.ids` should be a comma-separated list, and not an array? Maybe you should try `idsField.val().split( "," )`, and perhaps `console.log( idsField.val() )` for good measure too.

Comment: yes i have try to convert it to array and console log it but its not logging any thing on console, i think this `selection` function not triggering.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the js media API, but `selection` sounds like the wrong event/action - you need to be passing these ids when the modal is opened/init'ed.